# Chrome Plugin and Content Security Policy errors

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

When uploading my unpacked Chrome extension, I get the following error:

```
Could not load extension from '/Users/me/example'. Invalid value for 'content_security_policy': Both 'script-src' and 'object-src' directives must be specified (either explicitly, or implicitly via 'default-src'), and both must whitelist only secure resources. You may include any of the following sources: "'self'", "'unsafe-eval'", "http://127.0.0.1", "http://localhost", or any "https://" or "chrome-extension://" origin. For more information, see http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html
```

My manifest looks like the following:

```
{
  "name": "Example Inc.",
  "manifest_version" : 2,
  "version": "0.4.4",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "*://*.example.cc/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "production/jquery.libs.min.js",
        "https://example.cc/js/example.js"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "*://*.example.cc/*",
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "contextMenus",
    "storage",
    "management",
    "cookies"
  ],
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com/ga.js https://example.cc/js/*; object-src 'self'"
}
```

From all the examples I've seen, and after reading through some of the CSP docs, I'm not sure what I'm missing.  Our domain is fully https, the example.js file exists and is accessible, etc

Any ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

if you are only using your code set it to self only e.g.

"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self'; default-src 'self'",

Answer (score 0):

You should do:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com/ga.js https://example.cc; object-src 'self'"
```

Comment: To make this a better answer, explain what the problem was.

Comment: Using this entry, I get the following error when trying the upload:  Could not load extension from '/Users/me/example'. Could not load javascript '' for content script.

Comment: @Xan scroll up and read the original question